# AngularFire2 - Remove an item via Observable - last item doesn't remove from UI

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I was wondering why when I run this function, the item gets removed from my Firebase database, but inside my Angular 2 app, when it gets to the last entry, it removes it from the database, but it doesn't remove it from the list in my `*ngFor` loop. However, if I refresh the page, the list is updated and the entry is no longer there. Anyone know why this could be happening?

Here is the function in my provider to remove the attachment:

```
removeAttachment(attachment, projectId, requestId) {
    return this._af.database.list(`/check_requests/${projectId}/${requestId}/attachments/${attachment.id}`).remove();
  }
```

Here are the associated arrays in my component:

```
public attachments: any = [];
public attachmentKeys:any = [];
```

Here is an async function that populates the `attachments` and `attachmentKeys` arrays any time the database updates:

```
populateFormWithRequest() {
    this.formPopulationObs = this._checkRequests.getRequest(requestId, projectId).subscribe(requestData => {

      // Get the attachments
      if(requestData['attachments']) {
        this.attachments = requestData['attachments'];
        this.attachmentKeys = Object.keys(requestData['attachments']);
      }
   });
}
```

Here is my *ngFor loop in my html template:

```
<ul class="attachment-list" *ngIf="attachments && (attachments | mapToIterable).length > 0">
          <li *ngFor="let key of attachmentKeys">
            <a target="_blank" href="{{attachments[key].url}}"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i>{{attachments[key].name}}</a>
            <button (click)="removeAttachment(attachments[key], key)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely this line:

```ts
if (requestData['attachments']) {
```

When you remove the last attachment, the `attachments` property will not exist in the emitted request object. If a child in the Firebase database has no children, it too is removed.

So `requestData['attachments']` will be falsy and the `attachments` and `attachmentKeys` properties will remain unchanged.

The solution would be something like this:

```ts
if (requestData['attachments']) {
  this.attachments = requestData['attachments'];
  this.attachmentKeys = Object.keys(requestData['attachments']);
} else {
  this.attachments = {};
  this.attachmentKeys = [];
}
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. And I love you. Thankyou, that was perfect.